# How to run kaggle datasets on vscode on jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, api, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I am trying to connect the Kaggle kernel to the Jupyter notebook on VSCode. I have downloaded the Kaggle API for one of the projects and installed Kaggle in Jupiter notebook by doing:

```
> `!pip install kaggle`
```

but after running:

```
> import opendatasets

> opendatasets.download('https://www.kaggle.com/c/rossmann-store-sales')
```

while retrieving the dataset from Kaggle cause looping for Username input and give output like:

```
Please provide your Kaggle credentials to download this dataset. Learn more: http://kaggle-creds
Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your Kaggle username: Your
```

[Screessnhot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbJ2c.png)

I can't type in it. Can anyone help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got a prompt like this in the screenshot?

[image]

If I press `ESC` I will get the output like you.